# R stringr regex to extract characters within brackets

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to use regex in R to extract the entire string within brackets, where the brackets contain a keyword:

```
library(stringr)
test <- "asdf asiodjfojewl kjwnkjwnefkjnkf [asdf] fasdfads fewrw [keyword<1] keyword [keyword>1]"
```

Should return

```
keyword<1 # fine if it returns [keyword<1] with the brackets too instead
keyword>1
```

My attempt returns all of the letters individually and excludes the number from the brackets.

```
# my attempt
str_extract_all(test, regex("[\\<keyword\\>.*?]"))
[[1]]
 [1] "d" "o" "d" "o" "e" "w" "k" "w" "k" "w" "e" "k" "k" "d" "d" "d" "e" "w" "r" "w" "k" "e" "y" "w" "o" "r" "d" "<" "k" "e" "y" "w" "o" "r"
[35] "d" "k" "e" "y" "w" "o" "r" "d" ">"
```

Comment: you could try: `str_extract_all(test, "(?<=\\[)keyword.*?(?=\\])")`

Comment: That works! Can you submit that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: drj3122, don't be in such a rush to select an answer. The answer that seems to work for you may later be shown to be incorrect or better answers may be forthcoming. Many askers here wait at least a couple of hours before making a selection. Some wait quite a bit longer.

Comment: @AndS, that matches `'keywording'` in `'[keywording]'` and does not match `'keyword'` in `'[no keyword]'`. Note that while the keyword immediately follows the left bracket in the examples, the first sentence suggests that may not always be the case.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I only wrote a quick comment that answered the posed question. 'keywording' and 'no keyword' were not in the example, so I didn't try to take those into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
test <- "asdf asiodjfojewl kjwnkjwnefkjnkf [asdf] fasdfads fewrw [keyword<1] keyword [keyword>1]"
## If the word is right after "[":
str_extract_all(test, "(?<=\\[)keyword[^\\]\\[]*(?=])")
## If the word is anywhere betwee "[" and "]":
str_extract_all(test, "(?<=\\[)[^\\]\\[]*?keyword[^\\]\\[]*(?=])")
## =>
# [[1]]
# [1] "keyword<1" "keyword>1"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/lAE9zr).

The regexps match:

- `(?<=\[)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a `[` char to appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `keyword` - a literal string
- `[^\]\[]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `(?=])` - a positive lookahead that requires a `]` char to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qODShw/1).

Answer (score 3):

This creates the string ]...[ where ... is test and then split it on ]...[ where ... is the shortest string until the next [.  In the strsplit regex ] matches itself and then .*?\[ matches the shortest string until and including the next [. This returns a component for each component of test (assuming test could be a character vector) and then returns the results that have a < or > in them.  No packages are used.

```
test |>
  sprintf(fmt = "]%s[") |>
  strsplit("].*?\\[") |>
  lapply(grep, pattern = "[<>]", value = TRUE)
## [[1]]
## [1] "keyword<1" "keyword>1"
```